# Have there been measurements on how much faster CSS is than Javascript for coding an effect?

Tags: javascript, css, performance

I recently came across a CSS pseudo class that can do an effect for highlighting a form field, rather than using some custom javascript to do the same thing.  Another example is highlighting a table row using CSS rather than javascript.

So my question is: how much faster is it to use CSS than javascript for things like this?  Obviously we are talking in general terms, but there probably is a good rule of thumb for it.

I'm thinking this is a new avenue for me to get small performance gains on a page versus other methods I've used in the past.

Comment: By "an effect", do you mean an animation? If so, then most of the time during an animation, your code is simply waiting for the next frame update time.

Comment: Given that you can specify a duration for all CSS3 effects, isn't this a moot point?

Comment: No not an animation in a traditional sense.  CSS can give the appearance of an animation, but it's really tricking you by using multiple images.  Animation to me is more some interactive function that I would have opted to use javascript for in the past. Now I see that in some cases I could use CSS for this. I'm still using CSS 2.1 by the way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any stylistic effect that can be reasonably accomplished in CSS should absolutely be done in CSS rather than javascript. It will almost certainly perform better. The real benefit, though, is that using CSS to style things makes sense. That's what CSS is for.

Using javascript to style things that could be styled with CSS doesn't strike me as being any better than using tables for layout, or deprecated tags like `<font>` or `<center>` to get the appearance you desire... it's an unwelcome hack.

As for performance, unfortunately this kind of thing is hard to test. Normally you'd do performance testing by doing something over and over as fast as possible in a loop for, say, 5 seconds, and then doing something else as fast as possible for 5 seconds, and then seeing which thing was able to execute the most times in the allotted time. Since there's no way to automate hovering/unhovering an element without adding a bunch of overhead that would skew test results, it's difficult to test.

Comment: That is a good point!  Well I've been guilty of doing it in the past due to lack of knowledge about the power of CSS.

Comment: Fair enough, that's usually what I attribute that kind of thing to ;)

Comment: I mostly agree with this answer, but I think the real reasons for using css for styling when possible are (1) it helps to separate style information from substantive content and (2) it passes the details of implementing the styling on to the browser developers, and I think they are better suited to making sure it actually works correctly (or degrades well) on their browser.

Comment: @AdamCarter excellently put. I was just pointing out that styling things falls more in the CSS realm than the JS realm, which I assumed didn't really need any elaboration, but maybe I should clarify why that is.

Comment: The original question though speaks on what is the difference in performance, I'm sure it's considerable, but I don't know what the rule of thumb measure is.

Comment: @JamesDrinkard I don't think there's really a good way to test the performance, unfortunately. See my update.

Comment: Your answer got to the heart of the issue in any event. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do appreciate the other answers but there is also a bad side to css:

[No, css isn't always faster](http://briancrescimanno.com/css-dogma/)