# CSS3 vs Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making some Web Apps that need a quick response and have a significantly tight refreshing time. All I want is to save **memory** and **CPU Load**. My Question is:
Which is prefferable `CSS` or `Javascript/jQuery` in styling things like:

1. Visibility
2. Animation

I mean both are achievable from both respects and both seem ok. But I would like to be effective from the Structure. Any help will be appreciable.

Please be honest with the *core-level reason* if possible.

Thanks.

> And to those who marked this question duplicate:
>
> I am not looking for iPad Native Systems only. I am looking all
>   aproaches.

Comment: I would say css3 is probably always better than js when it comes to efficiency

Comment: Without expensive and heavy external JS libraries, animation is like re-inventing the wheel. CSS3 provides native support for it, so I'd choose that.

Comment: @Huangism Would you mind explaining in few lines?

Comment: If it's styling, try to use css as much as possible. Javascript is for behaviour and shouldn't be used to style elements. Of course, this is not always possible, and some scenarios might require javascript for more advanced styling.

Comment: CSS can take advantage of hardware acceleration, I'm not sure if JS can. At least not without extra work if so...

Comment: @xDNP It's one of those things I know by heart but I can't explain it in a way that is good enough for an answer. Fear not as someone will post an answer that is more dtailed than I can imagine

Comment: Too long of an article for me to read at work but seems pretty relevant:
http://davidwalsh.name/css-js-animation

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336778/have-there-been-measurements-on-how-much-faster-css-is-than-javascript-for-codin

Comment: I'd add the [fastest JavaScript animation library](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/) I've come across comes pretty close to CSS performance in case you want to see a [comparison](http://www.greensock.com/transitions/).

Comment: The answers for the duplicate question are generic.